# ClassCastException when using CircularFifoBuffer

Tags: java

Recently I tried to use CircularFifoBuffer class to store double[] arrays. And I initialize it with the following code:

```
Buffer ssvadFrmBuf = new CircularFifoBuffer(50);
for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
        ssvadFrmBuf.add(new double[512]);
}
```

Then I tried to retrieve individual double[] arrays via the following code:

```
Iterator<double[]> it= ssvadFrmBuf.iterator();
ArrayList<double[]> frameList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
for(int i=0;i < ssvadFrmBuf.size();i++)
{
    frameList.add(it.next());
}
```

Then I tried to run the Android application, and a ClassCastException is thrown. What is the problem? Can anyone please help LOL

Comment: And the exception says what?

Comment: @immibis Well nothing special, just java.lang.ClassCastException: [F

Comment: Please post the rest of the error. Also, are you sure `ssvadFrmBuf.iterator()` returns an `Iterator<double[]>`?

Comment: Just "[F"? Not "[F cannot be cast to [D" or similar?